# Conflict installing keras in anaconda in python2.7

Tags: deep-learning

When I type `conda install keras` i get this error:

"unsatisfiabledError:the following specification were found to be in conflict: -functools32   -keras"

I don't know that how to fix error, help me please.

Commands:

```
(my_pymc_env) C:\Users\MSI>conda install tensorflow 
Solving environment: failed 
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: - functools32 - tensorflow 
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

(my_pymc_env) C:\Users\MSI>pip install tensorflow 
Collecting tensorflow 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: elham I believe is means functools32 and keras have conflicting dependencies.
Try running `conda list` and post results here one of the packages on that list will need to be upgraded/downgraded I think.

Comment: Also you do have an environment setup and activated before you run install right?

Comment: sorry,i do n't know how to post package?Can you tell me the way?

Comment: what I meant was that you run the command `conda list` and whatever text comes out add it to your answer. When you paste your results highlight them and press Ctrl+K. You can read more about how to show your code in here at this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I could  install keras,But I still could not install tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

So keras requires tensorflow in other words I'd be very suprised if you succesfully installed keras without tensorflow. 
Output of the commands you ran tells us that have installed `functools32`

When I run `conda info tensorflow` I see that most recent version of tensorflow requires:

```
tensorflow 1.2.1 py36_0
-----------------------
file name   : tensorflow-1.2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
name        : tensorflow
version     : 1.2.1
build string: py36_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
size        : 21.0 MB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2017-08-05
license     : Apache 2.0
license_family: Apache
md5         : 736b26f0b1b83caee9d260859c7d0714
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/tensorflow-1.2.1-     
py36_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
   backports.weakref ==1.0rc1
   bleach ==1.5.0
   html5lib ==0.9999999
   markdown >=2.6.8
   numpy >=1.11
   protobuf >=3.2.0
   python 3.6*
   six >=1.10.0
   vs2015_runtime >=14.0.25420
   werkzeug >=0.11.10
```

And the I run `conda info functools32` I see:

```
functools32 3.2.3.2 py27_0
--------------------------
file name   : functools32-3.2.3.2-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : functools32
version     : 3.2.3.2
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
size        : 15 KB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2015-12-15
license     : PSF
md5         : 481667a7378f804fa65e2e2e81415b27
platform    : win32
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/functools32-3.2.3.2-        py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.7.*
```

Look at the dependencies of each package, you'll see that `tensorflow` requires python 3(`python 3.6.*`) and `functools32` requires python 2(`python 2.7.*`).
These packages require two different versions of python meaning they cannot be used together.

If you want use tensorflow or keras you need commit to python 3, functools32 is a library used in python 2, so best I can suggest is upgrade your python version.

Comment: good to hear, put a click on the check mark if this answer solved you problem or up arrow if it was helpful